# Github repo has files , but it was not showing in Jenkins workspace

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, jenkins, devops

I have entered my github repo url in scm  .and also entered github credentials correctly. my build is getting failed when we click on build now. And it was showing failed console output.
The error is

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 6522fd4f-bafc-4f90-89df-18bcfbe20d1a
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository https://github.com/ajayvarma8181/testb23_private.git
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/ajayvarma8181/testb23_private.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.32.0'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials github pat
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/ajayvarma8181/testb23_private.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/ajayvarma8181/testb23_private.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
Avoid second fetch
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: This looks like you have a problem with reaching your private repository. How are you installing your credentials to Jenkins to talk to GitHub?

Comment: I have creted a free style project and in that project selected configure > scm >git > credentials.

Comment: It seems Jenkins looks for a `master` branch. The name of the default branch is changed to `main` in many recent software releases, so you might have to change the branch that Jenkins is looking for to `main` as well.

Comment: Tnq u its working